# Issue in the calculus of inverse of terms from a list

Tags: summation, physics, filtering

to begin i want to warn you that i am a beginner in mathematica. I have to create a function that calculates the impedance total of an association of n (electronical) components.

So the formula is 1/Z(total) = sum of 1/Z(component).

Here the programm :

By knowing all the basic impedance (resistor, capacitor, inductor) I have to calculate the total impedance. So i wrote :

```
Z[Assos[comp_List], w_] := Simplify[( Total[1/Z[#, w] &])^-1]
```

but Mathematica does not work as i espected :(
here w represents the pulsation
I did not fully understand what does the # followed by &. To me it represents 1 term of the list, then it takes the next term. Am I Wrong ?

Can you help me by ? Or just some piece of advice ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `Z[list_] := Total[1/list]^-1`

Answer (score 4):

You want to calculate the impedance of some parallel circuit?

Here is a simple example. Assume that the impedances are contained in a list:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Now to get the impedance of the parallel circuit:

```
ztot = 1/ Total[1/list]

60/137
```

Answer (score 4):

*This is too lengthy for a comment; but, because the OP asked for some understanding, this should be interpreted as advice for learning.*

Try this:

```
tmpF = (1/f[#]) &
```

and this:

```
tmpF[x]  (*result: 1/f[x])
```

The first line produced a function called tmpF.
It produced a function because of the tailing &.
What is the placeholder for the argument of tmpF? That's the #.  So # with & is a way to produce a function.  For &, see the documentation for "pure function"; for #, see the documentation for Slot.

Now try:

```
tmp[{a,b,c}] (*result 1/f[{a,b,c}]*)
```

Do you see why? If not, try to figure that out.

Now try:

```
tmp[a,b,c]  (*result: 1/f[a]*)
```

Perhaps that's a bit puzzling? # is only the first argument of a function:it is synonymous to #1, and the second argument is #2.

A good exercise to teach yourself what is going on is try to create another function that takes three arguments produces 1/f[a,b,c].

Your initial attempt:

```
Z[Assos[comp_List], w_] := Simplify[( Total[1/Z[#, w] &])^-1]
```

has some peculiar aspects:

1: It looks like you are trying to create a function called Z that takes two arguments which would be called like this:  Z[a,b][x]

If so, the & needs to go at the end, and not in the inner part.

2: As constructed, your function (assuming you pay attention to 1) would only work when your first argument matches the pattern Assoc[someList]. You *probably* don't want that behavior, but there are some corner cases where you might.

3. Your function would be recursive: Z calls itself just like this:
   h[x_?IntegerQ] := h[x -1]h[x]
   and would need a stop condition such as
   h[0]=1

I hope this is helpful as you learn the language.

Comment: Thank you very much Craig ! I

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this particular calculation:

```
list = {Z1, Z2, Z3, Z4, Z5};
Divide @@ Through[{HarmonicMean, Length}[list]]
```

$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{Z1}}+\frac{1}{\text{Z2}}+\frac{1}{\text{Z3}}+\frac{1}{\text{Z4}}+\frac{1}{\text{Z5}}}$